# Nested While loop not working correctly php

Tags: php, while-loop

I am trying to get some data from my sql. But the result for the $arra_detail[] keeps repeating ... here is my code .. please review it and let me know of the mistake I am making .. any help will be appreciated ..

```
//Process of getting data from table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM projects JOIN project_details ON projects.project_id=project_details.project_id";

$results = $conn->query($sql);

            if($results->num_rows > 0){
               while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){

                   $pid = $row["project_id"];
                   $detailQuery = "SELECT * FROM project_details WHERE project_id = $pid";
                   $details = $conn->query($detailQuery);
                   if($details->num_rows > 0){
                       while ($r = $details->fetch_assoc()){
                           $projectDetails[] = array(
                               "project_detail" => $r["project_detail"],
                               "project_payment" => $r["project_payment"],
                               "project_payment_date" => $r["project_payment_date"],
                               "project_payment_status" => $r["project_payment_status"]
                           ); 
                       }
                   }

                   $data[$row["project_name"]] = array(
                       "project_id" => $row["project_id"],
                       "project_start_date" => $row["project_start_date"],
                       "project_due_date" => $row["project_due_date"],
                       "project_currency" => $row["project_currency"],
                       "poject_details" => $projectDetails
                   );


               }
               echo "<pre>",  print_r($data) , "</pre>";
            } else{
                echo "No data found ";
            }
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @esqew ... Thanks for the useful links and a handy tutorial ...

Answer (score 0):

use inner join query instead of two query with 2 loop

> SELECT * FROM projects,project_details WHERE
>   projects.project_id=project_details .project_id

Comment: Tried this .. but it is showing details of all the projects in one project ... Any ideas ???